# Bit counting arbitrarily large positive integers in C#

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, bit-manipulation, bitcount

There are many implementations of bit counting out there but in my case, I need to test if an arbitrarily large number contains at most two set bits.

I wrote the following function that does the job and seems to be quite fast but I wanted to find out if it can be further optimized for C#. This function gets called in a loop a few million times.

```
public static byte [] BitCountLookupArray = new byte []
{
    0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 8
};

// The parameter [number] will NEVER be negative.
public static bool HasSetBitCountOfLessThenThree (System.Numerics.BigInteger number)
{
    int sum = 0;
    byte [] bytes = null;

    bytes = number.ToByteArray();

    for (int i=0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += BitCountLookupArray [bytes [i]];
    }

    return (sum < 3);
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: The argument [number] sent to the function will **NEVER** be negative.

Some points I thought of were:

- Making the function static. Done.
- Using a static lookup array. Done.
- Using pointers instead of array indexes since the number of bytes often crosses 100,000. Not sure how much this would help.
- Forcing an inline function which sadly cannot be guaranteed in .NET.

Open to other suggestions.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure I understand. You say bit counting, yet you're using bytes?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: We are counting bits. They just happen to be available as a byte array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This way you can optimise it further

```
for (int i=0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    sum += BitCountLookupArray [bytes [i]];
    if(sum >= 3)
    {
         return false   // This will stop the execution of unnecessary lines  
                        // as we need to know whether sum is less than 3 or not.                         
    }
}

return true;
```

Comment: change `break;` to `return false;`  Change `return (sum < 3);` to `return true;`.  This will save a few more cycles.

Comment: @cadrell0: yes, that will be more optimized.

Answer (score 3):

Since you only need to know whether you have fewer than 3 set bits, I would suggest this:

```
// remove two bits
number &= number - 1;
number &= number - 1;
// if number != 0, then there were 3 or more bits set
return number.IsZero;
```

Of course Rain's method works too, and I'm not sure which strategy will be faster.

Alternative:

```
//remove one bit
number &= number - 1;
// if the number of bits left is 0 or 1, there were < 3 bits set
return number.IsZero || number.IsPowerOfTwo;
```

It's probably faster to test first, and remove the bit later:

```
return number.IsZero ||        // zero bits?
    number.IsPowerOfTwo ||     // one bit?
    (number & (number - 1)).IsPowerOfTwo;  // two bits?
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious optimisation is to drop out of the loop as soon as `sum == 3`, since any further matches past that point are immaterial.

There's also no need to set `bytes` twice; simply use `byte [] bytes = number.ToByteArray();`, but the benifit here is miniscule.